# Run as admin blocks the onDropped of DropTarget

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am trying to call this:

```
MoveFileEx(pChar(src), pChar(dest), MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED)
```

The program completes the `Copy` part, but it doesn't `Delete` the files after copying. I thought maybe I should run my application with `Administrative privileges`, but the moment I do, the `onDropped` event of my `DropTarget` gets blocked.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: the move file to a different disk drive impossible. this not related to any privilege.

Comment: @RbMm, Yes, Maybe, but on a different note the files that don't get deleted after move, that has to be because of privilege, am i correct?

Comment: try direct delete file, without move and copy and look to error. better via `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`

Comment: Search for UIPI.

Comment: @RbMm the whole point of using `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` is to allow moving files across disk drive boundaries. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) even says so: ""*If the destination is on another drive, you must set the `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` flag in `dwFlags`.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i mean native rename not alowed. and was traces of `ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE` before edit

Answer (score 4):

I could not say for sure why your source files are not being deleted.  Yes, you likely don't have permissions to delete them, only to copy them.  This is a documented possibility of [`MoveFileEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw):

> MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED
>   2 (0x2)
>
> If the file is to be moved to a different volume, the function simulates the move by using the CopyFile and DeleteFile functions.
>
> **If the file is successfully copied to a different volume and the original file is unable to be deleted, the function succeeds leaving the source file intact.**
>
> This value cannot be used with MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT.

However, regarding your `DragTarget`, when you run your app elevated, it runs at a higher integrity level, and "User Interface Privilege Isolation" (UIPI) blocks lower-integrity processes from communicating with UIs of higher-integrity processes.  In this case, UIPI is blocking the drag from a lower-integrity process from reaching your window, thus the `DragTarget` is not invoked, and there is no way (that I know of) to prevent that.

You have a few choices:

1. Don't elevate your app anymore, so that it runs at the same integrity level as most other non-elevated apps. Elevate only the code that needs to be elevated, ie the call to `MoveFileEx()`.  You can either:

   - Spawn a separate process just to call `MoveFileEx()`, using `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `runas` verb.  It can be a separate EXE, or it can be your main EXE with command-line parameters added to tell it what to do.
   - put the `MoveFileEx()` into a COM object that you instantiate when needed using the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/the-com-elevation-moniker).
2. if you must elevate your app, then implement a separate non-elevated app to accept drops, and then pass the dropped data to your elevated app using an IPC mechanism that UIPI does not block, such as a socket.
3. have your app handle the `WM_DROPFILES` window message instead of using a `DragTarget`.  Use `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()` to allow the `WM_COPYDATA`, `WM_DROPFILES`, and `WM_COPYGLOBALDATA` window messages to pass through UIPI.  This way, you will be able to drag files to your app, at least, but no other kinds of data that a `DragTarget` would otherwise allow.